# Arduino NRF24LO1

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, nrf24l01+

I have a problem with transmiter (Arduino uno) and receiver (Arduino nao). When I am trsmiting that I receive that: [image]

An this is my code for receiver

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>

#define CE_PIN  7
#define CSN_PIN 8

const byte thisSlaveAddress[5] = {'R','x','A','A','A'};

RF24 radio(CE_PIN, CSN_PIN);

char dataReceived[10]; // this must match dataToSend in the TX
bool newData = false;

//===========

    void setup() {
    
        Serial.begin(9600);
    
        Serial.println("SimpleRx Starting");
        radio.begin();
        radio.setDataRate( RF24_250KBPS );
        radio.openReadingPipe(1, thisSlaveAddress);
        radio.startListening();
    }
    
    //=============
    
    void loop() {
        getData();
        showData();
    }
    
    //==============
    
    void getData() {
        if ( radio.available() ) {
            radio.read( &dataReceived, sizeof(dataReceived) );
            newData = true;
        }
    }
    
    void showData() {
        if (newData == true) {
            Serial.print("Data received ");
            Serial.println(dataReceived);
            newData = false;
        }
    }
```

and transmitter

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>


#define CE_PIN  7
#define CSN_PIN 8

const byte slaveAddress[5] = {'R','x','A','A','A'};


RF24 radio(CE_PIN, CSN_PIN); // Create a Radio

char dataToSend[10] = "Message 0";
char txNum = '0';


unsigned long currentMillis;
unsigned long prevMillis;
unsigned long txIntervalMillis = 1000; // send once per second


void setup() {

    Serial.begin(9600);

    Serial.println("SimpleTx Starting");

    radio.begin();
    radio.setDataRate( RF24_250KBPS );
    radio.setRetries(3,5); // delay, count
    radio.openWritingPipe(slaveAddress);
}

//====================

void loop() {
    currentMillis = millis();
    if (currentMillis - prevMillis >= txIntervalMillis) {
        send();
        prevMillis = millis();
    }
}

//====================

void send() {

    bool rslt;
    rslt = radio.write( &dataToSend, sizeof(dataToSend) );
        // Always use sizeof() as it gives the size as the number of bytes.
        // For example if dataToSend was an int sizeof() would correctly return 2

    Serial.print("Data Sent ");
    Serial.print(dataToSend);
    if (rslt) {
        Serial.println("  Acknowledge received");
        updateMessage();
    }
    else {
        Serial.println("  Tx failed");
    }
}

//================

void updateMessage() {
        // so you can see that new data is being sent
    txNum += 1;
    if (txNum > '9') {
        txNum = '0';
    }
    dataToSend[8] = txNum;
}
```

Do you see an error?